# changing text-node value in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
// Create element
const loi  = document.createElement('li');

// Add class
loi.className = 'collection-item';

// Add id
loi.id = 'new-item';

// Add attribute
loi.setAttribute('title', 'New Item');

// Create text node and append
loi.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World'));

// Create new link element
const link = document.createElement('a');

// Add classes
link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';

// Add icon HTML
link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';

// Append link into li
loi.appendChild(link);

// Append li as child to ul
document.querySelector('ul.collection').appendChild(loi);

console.log(loi);
```

Here when I want to update the text-node which is hello-world, by writing `loi.textContent="ghg";` then that hello world is changed to `ghg`, but I missed those anchor tag, and I tag which I have created apart from this everything is there, I have attached the output screenshot also.

[image: Output-Screenshot]

Comment: i don't understand what you're asking. please  improve grammar, punctuation, context. what do you mean you "missed those anchor tag?" where did they go and why do you miss them?

Comment: @0.sh - he's not reassigning a constant. JS constants are not real constants. changing property values is completely legal.

Comment: FYI, your question just closed as a duplicate shouldn't have been (or at least, the dupetarge chosen was misleading). There's a difference between [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting a text node into `li`, it is the first child of `li` like you mentioned. You can access it with `loi.childNodes[0]` or use the read-only attribute `loi.firstChild` to verify.

```js
const loi  = document.createElement('li');

// Add class
loi.className = 'collection-item';

// Add id
loi.id = 'new-item';

// Add attribute
loi.setAttribute('title', 'New Item');

// Create text node and append
//const span = document.createElement("span");
//const text = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
//span.appendChild(text);
loi.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello World"));

// Create new link element
const link = document.createElement('a');

// Add classes
link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';

// Add icon HTML
link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';

// Append link into li
loi.appendChild(link);

// Append li as child to ul
document.querySelector('ul.collection').appendChild(loi);

const newText = document.createTextNode("New World");

console.log(loi.childNodes[0]);
loi.childNodes[0].replaceWith(newText);
//OR   loi.replaceChild(newText, loi.childNodes[0]);
```

```html
<ul class="collection"></ul>
```

Comment: It is working fine as now it is considering 1 st child of li ,but in many standard book they have mention that if we write something like  <ul><li >one <p>hghhh</p></li></ul> then li is the first child of ul,and text-content "one" is the first child of li and p is the second child of li and same thing I was applying in my code but it was not producing desired result.